# HTML5 Video and Jquery - Pause video for 3 seconds

Tags: jquery, html5-video

How can I pause a video for any seconds like 2 or 3 seconds and continue playing using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('yourVideoElementSelector')[0].play();
},2000);
```

Do you mean something like that per chance?

Or do you mean pause the playing video?

```
$('yourselector')[0].pause();
setTimeout(function(){ $('yourselector')[0].play();}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi, Pause the playing video.

Comment: if the video is already playing then the second code snippet should work out.